# Images floating, clearfix

Tags: css

I do not know how to describe the problem, hence please visit the link.

In this [(A)](http://www.trionestech.com/malaysia/ceiling-lights), the white background is rendered nicely, but if I added

```
<!-- Problem here -->
<ul class="thumb2"><li>
 <a href="/malaysia/ceiling-lights/8044-f610-255" title="">
  <img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/_8Uc0MYA0xgM/TXQ-BvHi-uI/AAAAAAAAAL4/vgYnsHjUziU/s220/8044f610255.jpg" title="" alt="" /></a>
</li></ul>
<!-- Problem here end -->
```

Then the page become [(B)](http://www.trionestech.com/test), the white background disappears.

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that all of the thumbnails are "floated."  See the CSS "float" property.  Floated elements do not take up page space.  To fix that, you can use some sort of CSS "clearfix" after all of the thumbnails.

The quickfix for this is to add:

```
<br style="clear: both;" />
```

After all of your thumbnails.

Another option is something like:

```
.spacer
{
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

And then you can add:

```
<div class="spacer"></div>
```

Nowadays, crazy hip developers are using something like:

http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

Comment: What's the advantage of the clearfix?  it looks a lot more involved that writing a `.clear` class.

Comment: Thanks John , your explanation help a lot

Comment: The advantage of the clearfix is that you don't have to create a separate element after the element you want to clear in order for the clear to work.  With the clearfix, you could have: <img ... style="float: left" class="clearfix" />, and a clear would be added after the image.  With a clear class, you have to do something like: <img ... /><div class="clear"></div>.  The clearfix preserves semantic HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
  <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
```

after the `</ul>`

The problem you are having has to do with your floated image elements. CSS can have difficulty calculating the height of a div that contains floated elements.

Comment: @peter. John's answer below is correct as well. You have used the example I gave other places in your code, so I went with that. Don't forget to accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> **JUST Replace your current code with the below codes. It will 100% work**

```
<style type="text/css">
   .clearfix {
      clear:both;
    }
</style>

<ul class="thumb2"><li>
 <a href="/malaysia/ceiling-lights/8044-f610-255" title="">
  <img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/_8Uc0MYA0xgM/TXQ-BvHi-uI/AAAAAAAAAL4/vgYnsHjUziU/s220/8044f610255.jpg" title="" alt="" /></a>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Comment: It might be better to add an explanation of what you're doing here, since this question was asked a very long time ago, the original questioner may not even see this.

Comment: I'm agree with your first comment. But "the original questioner may not even see this" this is not correct because if anyone getting trouble for the same problem then I think it will help them.:(